# How to add more advanced fields in each Gutenberg blocks?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

Is there any way to extend the [advanced field section](https://prnt.sc/k2apf0) in each Gutenberg blocks? I want to add more fields in each blocks. Please help.

Comment: please share some more details of what you want

Comment: this might help.https://riad.blog/2017/10/16/one-thousand-and-one-way-to-extend-gutenberg-today/

Comment: @EmptyBrain Sorry, I want to add custom attributes in each blocks. Like adding an option to add an ID in each block.

Comment: Thank you @raju_eww

Answer (score 0):

New answer: Try this. I made this to add inline styling to my blocks. I used isAdmin to define wether admin or not, to prevent author or other users to add inline styles everywhere. In your
index.js

```
/**
 * Inline Style component
 *
 * Shows a field for inline style only visible for admins
 * and adds a style attribute to the save content of the block
 */

import './attributes.js';
import './inspector.js';
```

inspector.js

```
const { __ } = wp.i18n;
const { select } = wp.data;
const { createHigherOrderComponent } = wp.compose;
const { InspectorAdvancedControls } = wp.blockEditor;
const { TextareaControl } = wp.components;

const withInspectorControls = createHigherOrderComponent((BlockEdit) => {
    return (props) => {

        const { inlineStyle } = props.attributes;
        const isAdmin = select( 'core' ).canUser( 'create', 'users' );

        return (
            <>
                <BlockEdit {...props} />
                { isAdmin ?
                    <InspectorAdvancedControls key="inspector">
                        <TextareaControl
                            label={__('Inline styling', 'custom-blocks')}
                            help={ __('Notice: This inline style will override any other inline style generated by Gutenberg.', 'custom-blocks') }
                            value={inlineStyle}
                            onChange={inlineStyle => props.setAttributes({ inlineStyle })}
                        />
                    </InspectorAdvancedControls>
                : '' }
            </>
        );
    };
}, 'withInspectorControl');

wp.hooks.addFilter('editor.BlockEdit', 'custom-blocks/inline-style/inspector', withInspectorControls);
```

attributes.js:

```
wp.hooks.addFilter('blocks.registerBlockType', 'custom-blocks/inline-style/attributes', function (settings, name) {
    settings = window.lodash.assign({}, settings, {
        attributes: window.lodash.assign({}, settings.attributes, {
            inlineStyle: {
                type: 'string',
                default: "",
            }
        })
    });
    return settings;
});

wp.hooks.addFilter('blocks.getSaveContent.extraProps','custom-blocks/inline-style/inspector',function(props, name, atts){

    if(atts['inlineStyle']!="")
        return lodash.assign(props, { style: atts['inlineStyle'] });

    return props;
});
```

Old answer:
As far as I know you can only add an input field to add and id to a block in the advanced field section.
However you can add custom sections to your inspector controls.
Basically there are two types of blocks: core blocks and custom blocks.

For custom blocks it is very simple, take a look at how to use a [Panel](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/components/panel/)

For core blocks, you need to use a filter:

1. `blocks.registerBlockType`: here you need to add attributes to the block you want to change
2. `blocks.getSaveContent.extraProps`: here you have to save the attributes
3. `editor.BlockEdit`: and here you can use the `Panel` to edit the block's inspector controls.